# support of merge query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I want to create a **merge query** so that I can insert the new incoming record and update the record if there is any change in record. I created a query as:

```
MERGE into sales AS TARGET 
USING sales1 AS SOURCE  
ON (TARGET.Order_ID = SOURCE.Order_ID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET  
THEN INSERT VALUES (select * from SOURCE)
```

But i am getting a error as **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MERGE"**.
My Postgres version is PostgreSQL 11.2
My question is in which version does PostgreSQL support **merge** query. So does PostgreSQL support merge query or not?

What this link[https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples] refer to? If this link is correct then how to execute **merge query** in PostgreSQL?

Comment: The link is not the manual, but the Wiki where ideas are documented or discussed. And you apparently overlooked the message at the top that says: "**This was never integrated into PostgreSQL, and requires significant work to be production quality**" - If you want to see what commands are supported, check the [SQL reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-commands.html) - you can use `insert on conflict` instead

Comment: So there is no such **merge query** in PostgreSQL its just a concept or idea which needs to be looked on.

Comment: There is no merge statement but you should look at the "Insert ... on confilct"

Comment: Okay, I have looked on Insert ... on conflict. One more thing this is [one](https://medium.com/@thomaspt748/how-to-upsert-data-into-relational-database-using-apache-spark-part-2-45a9d49d0f43) article it says using spark call merge query then what it is?

Comment: Your referenced article is about processing Merge in DB2, not Postgres. Different DBMS, different rules.

Comment: So ultimately it will not work in PostgreSQL, its something related to Informix database. There it says use merge query, then i searched of merge query in PostgreSQL where i found this wiki link of PostgreSQL. But when ran that merge query error came.